# CMake + Xcode builds executable but not dylib

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have a CMake C++ project that specifies both executable and library targets:

```
...
add_library(my_lib SHARED ${MY_MAIN_SOURCES})   
target_link_libraries(my_lib ${MY_MAIN_LIBS})

add_executable(all_tests util/test/run.cc ${MY_TEST_FILES} ${MY_MAIN_SOURCES}) 
target_link_libraries(all_tests ${MY_MAIN_LIBS})
```

If I build with Clang, everything works fine, I get both my 'all_tests' executable and my 'my_lib.dylib' library:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../..
make
```

However if I build with Xcode, I only get 'all_tests' and my library is missing.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Xcode ../..
xcodebuild
```

When I examine the generated Xcode project, I see that the failing library target lists dependencies on the rest of the project correctly, but it has no link step in its list of build phases.  However the working executable target is also similar, in that it lists dependencies and a compile step but no link step.  Is that somehow expected for a generated project?

Is there anything special I need to do in a CMake file to build dynamic libraries using Xcode?  (FWIW, building the same project on Windows generates both kinds of targets ok.)

(NB, The versions I am using are CMake 3.0.2 and Xcode 6.0.1;  are these compatible?  I am doing all this on OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks.)

Comment: Since you are using 6.0.1 XCode, I will also guess you are building for Yosemite? If on Yosemite, CMake 3.0.2 requires you to have the 10.10 SDK (if targetting for that platform) that isn't available with 6.01 XCode. You need the 6.1-beta XCode currently legally available to registered developers who pay $99/year. I'm not sure of the date XCode 6.1 will be available to the masses.

Comment: I'm still on Mavericks.

Comment: Ah okay. Was why I only commented but for someone who may help the target might be something to add to the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to have been that I was trying to compile an omnibus library from nothing but other libraries.  This was unclear in my original question (and indeed to me) because it turned out that both `MY_MAIN_SOURCES` and `MY_MAIN_LIBS` in the CMake file referred to other libraries in the project;  only `MY_TEST_FILES` referred to actual source code.

So to solve the problem, I added a dummy file:

```
 // Dummy.cc
 // namespace {
 // const int dummy = 0;
 // }
```

and included it in my build:

```
add_library(my_lib SHARED ${MY_MAIN_SOURCES} Dummy.cc)   
target_link_libraries(my_lib ${MY_MAIN_LIBS})
```

With this change, the generated Xcode project correctly outputs both the executable and the omnibus library.